# How to generate SQL CLR stored procedure installation script w/o Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, msbuild, clrstoredprocedure

I am working on CLR stored procedure using VS2010. I need to generate standalone deployment script to install this procedure at customer servers. Now I am using Visual Studio which generate such script when I press F5 and try to debug SP on DB server. This script is placed at `bin\Debug\MyStoredProcedure.sql` file. It looks like this:

```
USE [$(DatabaseName)]

GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE id=OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpErrors')) DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmpErrors (Error int)
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
PRINT N'Dropping [dbo].[spMyStoredProcedure]...';


GO
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyStoredProcedure];


GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0
   AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END

IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error)
        VALUES                 (1);
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    END


GO
PRINT N'Dropping [MyStoredProcedure]...';


GO
DROP ASSEMBLY [MyStoredProcedure];


GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0
   AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END

IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error)
        VALUES                 (1);
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    END


GO
PRINT N'Creating [MyStoredProcedure]...';


GO
CREATE ASSEMBLY [MyStoredProcedure]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
-- here should be long hex string with assembly binary
    FROM 0x4D5A90000300000004000000FFFCD21546869732070726F6772616D...000000000000000000 
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;


GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0
   AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END

IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error)
        VALUES                 (1);
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    END


GO
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[spMyStoredProcedure]...';


GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyStoredProcedure]
@reference UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @results INT OUTPUT, @errormessage NVARCHAR (4000) OUTPUT
AS EXTERNAL NAME [MyStoredProcedure].[MyCompany.MyProduct.MyStoredProcedureClass].[MyStoredProcedureMethod]


GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0
   AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END

IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error)
        VALUES                 (1);
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    END


GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmpErrors) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 BEGIN
PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update succeeded.'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update failed.'
GO
DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
```

I am wondering, is it possible to generate such script without Visual Studio? For example, what if I build solution with MSBuild and then generate this script with some tool? I believe, that if I read assembly as byte array and then serialize it to hex string and insert into script template - it could work, but maybe there is some easier standard solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it seems that the only way is to read assembly as binary file and then generate script using template above. Something like that:

```
            using (var str = File.OpenRead(pathToAssembly))
            {
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[1024];
                    count = str.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        hexStringBuilder.Append((buffer[i] >> 4).ToString("X"));
                        hexStringBuilder.Append((buffer[i] & 0xF).ToString("X"));
                    }
                } while (count > 0);
            }
            // generate script using template from initial question
```

I've checked this approach and it works.

Comment: This is great and much faster than trying to `FROM 'C:\FilePath'`, I also had to prepend `0x` to the hex as in `FROM 0xhexWithoutQuotes`.

Answer (score 5):

Alternately, assuming you have the assembly deployed direct from visual studio to some test SQL server; create a standalone deployment script by right clicking the assembly in SSMS (management studio) and select:

> Script assembly as -> Create To...

This will write the hex string representing the DLL for you in an SQL script you can use for a single file deployment.

Comment: This won't be a viable solution when aiming at a CI/CD pipeline...

Answer (score 1):

What you've described should work fine but as [Deploying CLR Database Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345099.aspx) describes it seems easier to just to reference the compiled Dll.

> To deploy the assembly using
>   Transact-SQL
>
> Compile the assembly from the source
>   file using the command line compilers
>   included with the .NET Framework.
>
> For Microsoft Visual C# source files:
>
> csc /target:library C:\helloworld.cs
>
> For Microsoft Visual Basic source
>   files:
>
> vbc /target:library C:\helloworld.vb
>
> These commands launch the Visual C# or
>   Visual Basic compiler using the
>   /target option to specify building a
>   library DLL.
>
> Resolve all build errors and warnings
>   before deploying the assembly to the
>   test server.
>
> Open SQL Server Management Studio on
>   the test server. Create a new query,
>   connected to a suitable test database
>   (such as AdventureWorks2008R2).
>
> Create the assembly in the server by
>   adding the following Transact-SQL to
>   the query.
>
> CREATE ASSEMBLY HelloWorld from
>   'c:\helloworld.dll' WITH
>   PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
>
> The procedure, function, aggregate,
>   user-defined type, or trigger must
>   then be created in the instance of SQL
>   Server. If the HelloWorld assembly
>   contains a method named HelloWorld in
>   the Procedures class, the following
>   Transact-SQL can be added to the query
>   to create a procedure called hello in
>   SQL Server.
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE hello
>
> AS
>
> EXTERNAL NAME
>   HelloWorld.Procedures.HelloWorld

Comment: I know about this solution, but its not applicable - our customer want to have single-file deployment script.

Comment: @Victor ah. then yes I think you had it right with " I read assembly as byte array and then serialize it to hex string and insert into script template -"

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](https://www.benday.com/2012/12/18/deploy-a-sql-server-database-projects-dacpac-with-sqlpackage-exe/) post and instead of use **/Action:Publish** use **/Action:Script /OutputPath:D:\deploymentScript.sql**

Answer (score 0):

You can get the assembly binary from sys.assembly_files. Perhaps you can do something with that.

```
select *
from sys.assembly_files
```